# Bootable installer drive disappears in Recovery Mode; can't install

Tags: macbook-pro, install, recovery

Hopefully you all can help.

My sister managed to delete her entire Macbook drive including MacOS somehow, I think she was messing around in Disk Utility...

The Macbook will not install through Internet Recovery or connect to the internet at all actually.

I have tried installing from a bootable installer which appears briefly on Recovery Mode but then disappears in a comic book poof of smoke! I think this is because it has the T2 security chip (and since the OS is deleted, there's no way to change the settings on that!)

Tried using time machine and connecting my Macbook with hers; her Macbook does not recognise mine at all.

I can't access terminal or anything else. It has a "MacOS installer" on there but it fails to install from it.

Do I need to take it to an Apple Store at this point or is there anything that can be done?

Comment: You say "bootable installer drive" but also say you are booting into Recovery Mode, which are mutually exclusive. Hold down the OPTION key with the bootable installer inserted and if it is truly bootable it will allow you to select the installer drive and boot from it. If not you need to use your Mac to create a bootable installer. Apple has instructions but I have found MacWorld's a little more helpful https://www.macworld.com/article/671308/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-macos-installer.html

Comment: Which MacBook is this and what version is on the installer - Ventura?  Did you make it somewhere?  How?

Comment: @SteveChambers Perhaps it isn’t called Recovery Mode? I do mean the screen after pressing option, I’ve created a MacOS Sierra bootable installer (this was the only version of the OS I was able to download on the Apple website) - it appears briefly for 1 or 2 seconds then disappears before I’m able to click it.

Comment: Sierra won't run on anything with a T2 chip. You need to answer the questions already asked before we can get any further. BTW, Internet Recovery works much better on hard-wired Ethernet.

Comment: Pressing OPTION at boot chooses the boot device *it is not Recovery Mode.* If you would answer the questions already asked (as @Tetsujin suggests) we might be able to help you.

Comment: @DougMasters Yeah I made it using my own Mac, following the instructions here - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251386184 (to get round a common error)

Comment: @Tetsujin I’ve tried Internet Recovery over ethernet, it makes no difference! I suspected the Sierra may be the problem, but I can’t seem to download the newer versions because the app store won’t let me download (either because I already have that macOS or because it’s too advanced for my Macbook!)

Comment: @SteveChambers see I thought that was the start of Recovery Mode aha, anyway it doesn’t get past that screen!

Comment: We really need to know exactly which Mac it is. That affects many things, including which is the best OS to go for. If your own Mac is already running anything from Mojave upwards, then get [MDS](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/) from Two Canoes [freeware] which can make proper bootable sticks for anything from High Sierra up.

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought i’d said - my sister’s is a 2019 Macbook Air Intel i5. Not sure what the screen size is -  13/14” maybe?  My own Mac runs Big Sur 2017 Intel Macbook Air i3. I’ll have a look at MDS.

Comment: OK, so the earliest OS it can run will be Mojave, 10.14, the latest is current, Ventura. The next hurdle may be if the T2 chip is preventing boot from USB. If so then you have to be able top get to recovery to switch that. idk what happens if you can't - it might mean a trip to an Apple Store with proof of ownership [but I'm not familiar with that process, so others may have better knowledge]